# X-Frame-Options in Magento 2.3.5-p1

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1, iframe, content-security-policy

I've set X-Frame-Options
`'x-frame-options' => '*',`
in env as mentioned in the doc
[Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/secy/secy-xframe.html)

But still I'm getting this error

> Refused to display 'https://mythridpartyurlhere.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you allow iframes to load from any URL it does not mean the third party resource allows you to.

If you read the error carefully it mentions the third party URL itself has `sameorigin` set and not your Magento installation.

> Refused to display 'https://mythridpartyurlhere.com/' in a frame because **it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'**.

There is nothing you can do about this, the third party does not allow you to load this resource in an iframe on your website.

To confirm this check the response headers on the resource:

[image]